# How to implement a subtotal of all orders?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

The following, renders: `Subtotal: P[object Object]`

It seems that subtotal is returning the promise object instead of th sum of all orders. `VARIATION 2` also returns a promise.

How should I go about calculating the subtotal of all products?

```
  // app/controllers/application.js
  import Ember from 'ember';

  export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({    
    subtotal: function() {
      // VARIATION 1:
      var productCollectionPromises = this.get('orders').getEach('product');
      var sum = 0;

      return Ember.RSVP.all(productCollectionPromises).then(function(productCollections){
        productCollections.forEach(function(product){
          sum += product.get('amountInCents');
        });

        return sum;
      });

      // VARIATION 2:
      // return this.get('orders').mapBy('product').reduce(function(previousValue, product) {
      //   return previousValue + product.get('amountInCents');
      // }, 0) / 100;
    }.property('orders.@each.total'),
  });

  // app/templates/application.hbs
  <br /><strong>Subtotal:</strong> ${{subtotal}}
```

Comment: Can you throw up a jsbin of this? It would make it easier to figure out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ember.RSVP.all` returns a promise, which is what you are returning, you can just make an observer and update `subtotal` on change:

```
// app/controllers/application.js
  import Ember from 'ember';

  export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    subtotal: null,
    totalsChanged: function() {
      var productCollectionPromises = this.get('orders').getEach('product');
      var sum = 0;

      Ember.RSVP.all(productCollectionPromises).then(productCollections => {
        productCollections.forEach(function(product){
          sum += product.get('amountInCents');
        });

        this.set('subtotal', sum);
      });
    }.observes('orders.@each.total'),
  });
```